# Create custom Xterm keybindings for copying, pasting using the clipboard

Tags: linux, terminal, clipboard, x11

I am trying to create custom keybindings in Xterm that will allow me to copy and paste text from/to the X11 clipboard. I am currently able to paste from the clipboard using the default `Shift + Insert` (after adding `XTerm*selectToClipboard: true` in my ~/.Xresources file) but this is awkward on my keyboard and I would like something else. My terminal has Vi keybindings and I would like to bind `p` in command mode to paste and `y` to yank/copy. I tried adding this to ~/.Xresources and reloading with `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`:

```
!! New copy, paste
XTerm*VT100*translations: #override \n\
    p:  insert-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    y:        select-end(CLIPBOARD)
```

... but it doesn't work. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant something like this:

```
XTerm*selectToClipboard: true
XTerm*VT100*translations: #override \n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>P:  insert-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>Y:        select-end(CLIPBOARD)
```

I added modifiers to limit the scope of the translation to avoid having *every* `P` and `Y` trigger the actions and the `<Key>` marker to explain to the library what `P` and `Y` *are*.

Comment: This works well, but is there a way to have separate bindings for the different modes, e.g. insert and command mode?

Comment: That's possible using the `keymap` resource, but switching keymaps isn't automatic - you would have to press a special key to switch keymaps.